# Export to .csv File

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I had problem with export data to .csv file. I use 2 methods.

```
        Encoding csvEncoding = new UTF8SignatureEncoding();
        byte[] csvFile = TestByte(CsvContentDelimiter.NewLine, CsvContentDelimiter.Semicolon, csvEncoding);


        string attachment = String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.csv", "docs_inv");

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.ContentEncoding = csvEncoding;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", attachment);
        Response.BinaryWrite(csvFile);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

And

```
    public byte[] TestByte(CsvContentDelimiter rowDelimiter, CsvContentDelimiter columnDelimiter, Encoding encoding)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("product;");
        return encoding.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    }
```

This code create .csv file, but file have bad Encoding and i see only some "hash"

Comment: are you sure you see a hash? don't you see a hexadecimal version of the file? If so, try to open it in some other text editor (e.g. notepad2)

Comment: I'm sure, i Open it by Notepad++..

Comment: so try to change BinaryWrite to Write as mentioned @Belogix. But if it is possible, dont use \r\n, use string.Format("Record1,Fred,23{0}", Environment.NewLine) instead

Comment: Response.Write doesn't help. I cant write string like "Record1,Fred,23\r\nRecord2,Bob,36\r\n"

Comment: When you say you can't, what is the issue?

Comment: Have you tried the *EXACT* code in my example? I.e. Remove formatting etc? Does that work? If not it might point to an issue with your setup.

Comment: is UTF8SignatureEncoding your own encoding?

Comment: Yes, its my type with BOM.

Comment: OK, I've updated my example which is the same as your code above in fully working web application. It exports file perfectly so suggests either your data is getting corrupted or your encoding is at fault. Please try my example below and you might have to post your encoding code.

Comment: I have try Your code and still I have some Hash i .csv File i don't know why.... :/

Comment: Hmm, that is very strange! If you are using the code in my answer then you should definitely get valid output as I've tried it here! How are you running your project? Via VS(2010?) or is it hosted in IIS?

Comment: Another thing to try is create a new page and post the code from my example on to it. It might be something strange with that particular page?

Comment: Hmmm.... i find the problem but i don't know how fix this. On my page.aspx i have <asp:FileUpload> and when this Control is set - Export stop working (Hash problem), but when i delete <asp:FileUpload> Control from page.aspx Export work just fine! WTF?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fully working example using UTF8 formatting. It uses your own code so shows that it is your Encoding that is causing the issue:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Use UTF8 encoding
            Encoding csvEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            byte[] csvFile = TestByte(csvEncoding);

            string attachment = String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.csv", "docs_inv");

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.ContentEncoding = csvEncoding;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", attachment);
            Response.BinaryWrite(csvFile);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }

        public byte[] TestByte(Encoding encoding)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("Record1,Fred,Bloggs,26{0}", Environment.NewLine);
            sb.AppendFormat("Record2,John,Smith,32{0}", Environment.NewLine);
            return encoding.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do 
Response.Write(s1);
Where s1 = "Record1,Fred,23\r\nRecord2,Bob,36\r\n";